# In an asp.net-mvc site, is there a better way to get the full base URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

I have an asp.net-mvc site and I send out a lot of email from my site.  Before I used to send email from my controller and I used this code to get the base url:

```
    protected string GetBaseUrl()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"));
    }
```

that is because i obviously need fully formed URL.  so in a normal link on a page that i have href="/GoHere", i would want that to translate to:

```
  "http://www.mysite.com/GoHere"
```

not just relative URLs given that they are going in emails like

```
  "/GoHere"
```

I am now refactoring my controller to move all of this code outside of it, but i find myself passing this baseURL string around (because the function above relies on Request which is in namespace:

```
  System.Web
```

and I can't seem to access this request object outside the controller class.  Right now I am passing a string **BaseURL** all over the place so when i need to generate the emails, i can append the relative URL after the base URL but that feels very hacky

Is there a better way to get the baseURL (either through the Request object or not) outside of a controller class in an asp.net-mvc website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UrlHelper.Action` has an overload that accepts "protocol". Use this to generate full urls that conform to your routing table.

```
var baseUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

[MSDN Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505232%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

In a default project MVC with default routing, this would return something like:

```
http://mydomain.com
```

Note that if you can't use/access the `HttpRequest` object, consider passing in the scheme or if you know it's always "https" (for example) then you can use a magic (hard coded) string or read it from a settings/config file.

You can access the HttpRequest object outside of the controller by using:

```
var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
```

On a similar note, you will have the same problem accessing the UrlHelper instance of the controller. You can create an instance like so:

```
var url = new UrlHelper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
```

`HttpRequest.RequestContext` is new to .NET 4.0. I thought I'd not that seeing as though you haven't specified a working version. [MSDN source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.requestcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: but how do you access the Request object outside the controller?

Comment: thanks . . so i am able to get the request object using Current.Request but i now need to figure out how to replicate that last argument (            Url.Content("~")) . .  do you know what Url.Content("~") is providing?

Comment: Url.Content("~") is the root path. You don't need to use that if there's a valid action behind the url you're trying to consume. Just use the "action" and "controller" parameters of Url.Action and let routing take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is determining the `baseURL` programmatically as it is highly relative and a website is reachable at many URLs. For example:

```
* http://localhost/GoHere             locally
* http://localhost:8080/GoHere        locally on another port
* http://127.0.0.1/GoHere             locally by the loop back address
* http://10.0.10.5/GoHere             the internal IP of the machine
* http://72.34.56.78/GoHere           the public IP of the machine
* http://www.mysite.com/GoHere        preferred public URL
* http://www.bestsiteever.com/GoHere  SEO URL
```

It would be easier to set the `baseURL` in a config file, a database by customer, or whatever way you need to correlate the `baseURL` to the email.

Comment: I am just trying to replicate what my code in GetBaseUr() does